# Recover sql server 2000 sa password

Tags: sql-server, password-recovery

I had forgotten my SQL server 2000 sa username password and now i am not able to connect to it. previously i had disabled windows authentication and had only username sa.

Now I ant to recover / reset my password of sa.. How can i do that

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to simply reset the password by connecting with a domain/local admin (so you may need help from your system administrators), but this only works if SQL Server was set up to allow local admins (these are now left off the default admin group during setup).

If you can't use this or other existing methods to recover / reset the SA password, some of which are explained here:

You can check here:

http://p2p.wrox.com/sql-server-2000/6725-forgot-sa-password-unable-change-help.html

http://www.sqlrecoverytool.com/how-to-reset-sql-password.html

Comment: I tried to follow the instruction at the first link.. it says login failed for server\administrator... while trying to expand the server at enterprise manager, is there any other tryouts..

Comment: What about the second link??? you can check there also there is some tryout available on that very page.